# Video shows up as green static when I try to make a video call! Need help!

Tags: google

I use a Dell inspiron 15 with a Intel 3D real sense camera. Every time I log into hangouts for a video chat, all I get is green static, almost like white noise but green. I have tried to switch cameras and play with my windows settings to not avail. Has this happened to anyone? Does anyone. Have any suggestions? I'm desperate for help!!

Comment: What browser are you using? What version of Ubuntu? Does the camera stream show okay in the included `Cheese Webcam Booth` application?